# Memory leak coming from this code, how do i get rid of it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

This is my code, which the app runs upon changing to the view that it's inside of. It's causing a memory leak with colourButtonsArray when you change to this view more than once (so not the first time you run it) but i'm unsure how to get rid of it:

```
-(void)setColours {

        colourButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [colourButtonsArray addObject:@""];


    int buttonsI = 1;

    while (buttonsI < 7)
    {
        //Make a button
        UIButton *colourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        colourButton.frame = CGRectMake((53*(buttonsI-1))+3, 5, 49, 49);
        colourButton.tag = buttonsI;
        [colourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(colourButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [colourView addSubview:colourButton];


        [colourButtonsArray addObject:colourButton];


[colourButton release];
    buttonsI++;
}
```

}

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't be releasing `colourButton`. You can use a `for` instead of the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you release `colourButtonsArray`?

If you call `setColours` more than once you'll be creating a new array for `colorButtonsArray` and leaking the old one each time (assuming you only release `colourButtonsArray` in your dealloc method, or if you don't release it at all).

Comment: If i put [colourButtonsArray release]; in dealloc, then when i load the view for the second time, it crashes.

Comment: ...a leak won't immediately cause a crash. Are you sure you're not confusing terminology here? A leak is when you don't release your object, and it remains stuck in memory taking up space. If you repeatedly leak memory you'll eventually cause a crash (through an out of memory error), but not with a single array such as this. Sounds like something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

use accessors properly, and lock as necessary. this may help:

```
-(void)setColours {
/* lock if necessary */
    self.colourButtonsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.colourButtonsArray addObject:@""];

    int buttonsI = 1;

    while (buttonsI < 7)
    {
    /* Make a button */
        UIButton *colourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        colourButton.frame = CGRectMake((53*(buttonsI-1))+3, 5, 49, 49);
        colourButton.tag = buttonsI;
        [colourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(colourButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.colourView addSubview:colourButton];

        [self.colourButtonsArray addObject:colourButton];

        // no release here: [colourButton release];
        buttonsI++;
    }

/* unlock if necessary */
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'lock'? I don't understand.